# Set category of a New Email Message Before I Send

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I can easily set the category of an email I receive using the categorize drop down. However, I want to be able to set the category of an email I send. I could send it, then go in to Sent Items afterward, but I'd really prefer to have the categorize drop down on the ribbon of the new mail message so I can set the category before I hit send. However, I can't find that anywhere in the customize ribbon stuff.

I can open up tags, and do it in there, but I'd rather have the quick access that I have in other ribbons (such as categorizing an email I receive.)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You need this; if no category is set, the send operation is cancelled:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim oc As OlObjectClass
    oc = item.Class
    If oc = olMail Or oc = olReport Or oc = olMeetingRequest Then
        item.ShowCategoriesDialog
        item.BillingInformation = item.Categories
        If item.Categories = "" Then Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

BillingInformation is set too, since it's transmitted back *unaltered* when your recipients reply, so incoming answers are already categorized properly.... for that to work you'll need this as well:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim arr() As String, i As Integer
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim itm, m As MailItem

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ns = Application.Session
    arr = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Set itm = ns.GetItemFromID(arr(i))
        If itm.Class = olMail Then
            Set m = itm
            If m.Categories = "" And m.BillingInformation  "" Then
                m.Categories = m.BillingInformation
                m.BillingInformation = ""
                m.Save
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Regards MF